# Access submodule files on server

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have used git sub module as follows:

```
git submodule add git:<repository>.git
```

It works fine and I can see directory for the project inside my current directory.

Then I did:

```
git config --global status.submoduleSummary true
git commit -am "push"
git push origin master
```

On git hub it shows something like this.
[image]

However when I try to access these sub module files on server it shows empty directory. How to solve this ?

Comment: Is the submodule also available at Github?

Comment: Yes but Just a link to other repository as I have shown in the screenshot.

Comment: That's ok, that's how github presents submodules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add the repository as submodule, now you have to initialize it.

Use `git submodule update --init --recursive` to initialize and update the submodules recorded in the index.